# Customised registration module in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, registration

I want to have multiple registration forms or fields depending per the type of user. I am having some of the data already stored in my database and I want that during registration, those fields should be matched. If the match is successful, then the person will be registered else not.

I request if someone can tell me about any free extension/plugin for the same or any documentation of using which I can code a module as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a copy of the core profile plugin and change the name in the xml. THen you will be able to add different xml files and load them conditionally and in your plugin you will code whatever you want to happen using the various user events related to registering and saving.

Comment: Thanks. But can i get any documentation about the same where I can read if i face any problem.